# Arrogant little fella

Tags: riddle, word

> I see everything.
>
> I hear everything.
>
> I am all that you know.
>
> Because of that I choose what I am.

What am I?

Comment: Why was this closed?

Comment: @mestackoverflow it is closed because they say it is based upon opinion what the answer could be, though I only saw 1 answer which was correct and no other speculations....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> A brain?

I see everything.

> Gets all data from the eyes

I hear everything.

> Gets all data from the ears

I am all that you know.

> Literally contains all your knowledge

Because of that I choose what I am.

> As such, it must have been a brain that came up with the word 'brain'

Comment: I thought that too, but it doesn't literally see or hear everything. Actually, it knows that itself doesn't know everything. Haha, this might become a "If a tree falls in a forest" discussion.

Comment: It is what I had in mind, @Noctilucente well it does connect everything so you can hear, see and know things. Good luck doing all of that without a brain :)